# how to I return the index of multiple characters in a string when running a for loop?

Tags: python, string

I have the following code:

```
dup = ["aaa","bbb","ccc"]

s = "hfidgfaaahjfihdfhd"

for duplicate in dup:
    if duplicate in s:
        print(s.index(duplicate))
```

The `output is 6`; which is the index of the first character of "aaa" in the string s, however, I would like it to print all three of its indexes, i.e. 6,7,8.
Is there anyway I can tweak the code to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, the easiest tweak you could do is: instead of printing just the index of the duplicate, print all the numbers starting from the index of the duplicate up to index of the duplicate + length of the duplicate, like this:

```
   dup = ["aaa","bbb","ccc"]
    
    s = "hfidgfaaahjfihdfhd"
    
    for duplicate in dup:
        if duplicate in s:
            print(*list(range(s.index(duplicate), s.index(duplicate) + len(duplicate))))
```

Here, I am using the `list(range())` function to generate a list of all the numbers within the range `s.index(duplicate)` up to (but not included!) `s.index(duplicate) + len(duplicate)`.

The asterisk at the beginning is used to unpack the list and print each value individually instead of printing it as a list: without the asterisk, you would get [6, 7, 8]. With the asterisk, you should get exactly 6 7 8.

An easier alternative, but with the exact same logic, would be this:

```
dup = ["aaa","bbb","ccc"]

s = "hfidgfaaahjfihdfhd"

for duplicate in dup:
    if duplicate in s:
        for index in range(s.index(duplicate), s.index(duplicate) + len(duplicate)):
            print(index)
```

You can avoid the `*list(range())` using a regular for loop with the range function

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do it by this way:

```
dup = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']

s = "hhdahwhdaaadfewfeas"

for i in range(0, len(s), len(dup[0]) - 1):
    string_to_check = s[i:3+i:]
    if dup[0] == string_to_check:
        for j in range(0, len(string_to_check)):
            print(f'Index for the letters: {j + i}')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using regular expressions ([`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)) for this (in particular [`Match.span()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.span)):

```py
import re

dup = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]

s = "hfidgfaaahjfihdfhd"

for duplicate in dup:
    # finditer returns an iterator over all found matches
    matches = re.finditer(duplicate, s)

    for match in matches:
        # The span() method returns a tuple containing
        # the start and end position of the match.
        # These can be passed into the built-in range() function
        # to generate the indices you are interested in:
        print(f"Match for '{duplicate}':", *range(*match.span()))
```

Will print:

```
Match for 'aaa': 6 7 8
```

If you now changed `s` to `"hfidgfaaahjfihdfhdaaabbb"`, the result would be:

```
Match for 'aaa': 6 7 8
Match for 'aaa': 18 19 20
Match for 'bbb': 21 22 23
```